# Dimension of an Eigenspace

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Best regards!

I would not know how to start this exercise, I have problems finding the dimension. Any contribution would be well received. Thank you very much!

Let $e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4$ be the standard basis of $\Bbb {C^4}$ and consider the set $V$ of those
matrices $A\in \Bbb {M_4(C)}$ with the property that $e_1, e_2$ are both eigenvectors of $A$.
Prove that $V$ is a vector subspace of $\Bbb {M_4(C)}$ and compute its dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The seta $V$ is the set of all matrices of the type$$\begin{pmatrix}a&0&a_{13}&a_{14}\\0&a'&a_{23}&a_{24}\\0&0&a_{33}&a_{34}\\0&0&a_{43}&a_{44}\end{pmatrix},$$
beacause, since $e_1$ is an eigenvector, $A.e_1$ is of the form $ae_1$ for some $a\in\mathbb C$ and, since $e_2$ is an eigenvector, $A.e_2$ is of the form $a'e_2$ for some $a'\in\mathbb C$. Besides this, there are no other restrictions on the form of the elemnts of $V$. It is clear then that it's a vector space. Furthermore, $\dim V=10$.

Comment: How do you deduce the form of the matrices of $V$?

Comment: Since $e_1$ is an eigenvector, $A.e_1$ is of the form $ae_1$ for some $a\in\mathbb C$ and since $e_2$ is an eigenvector, $A.e_2$ is of the form $a'e_2$ for some $a'\in\mathbb C$. Besides this, there are no other restrictions on the form of the elemnts of $V$.

Comment: @yanko Good idea. I shall do that.

Comment: I have already understood,thanks!